# Is it possible to setup vhost in one file and setup rewrites for this vhost in another file? (without using .htaccess)

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

Is it possible to setup `VirtualHost`, but include it's rewrites from another file? Using `.htaccess` is not allowed. Something like this, I suppose...

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.12>
SetEnv APP_ENV dev
...
Include /path/to/vhostrewrite.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. I'd recommend putting your includes in an `IfModule` tag as well, e.g:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Include conf/mod_rewrite_rules.conf
</IfModule>
```

Configuration changes to the rewrite rules will require a reload of the entire configuration as opposed to `.htaccess`.